# Is there a way to configure Django Rest Framework to store token information in Redis rather than the Database?

Tags: django, redis, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to configure Django Rest Framework to store token information in Redis rather than the Database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own custom authentication backend which stores tokens in redis. From [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication):

> To implement a custom authentication scheme, subclass BaseAuthentication and override the .authenticate(self, request) method. The method should return a two-tuple of (user, auth) if authentication succeeds, or None otherwise.