# Trying to implement a passwordless authentication using Redis and random tokens

Tags: django, security, redis, token

I want to implement a passwordless email based authentication (like in medium.com!), now I want to verify if this logic flow is secure or not:

1. User submits his email
2. Server generates a random token, sets to Redis a new value where the KEY is the token, the VALUE is the email or the corresponding user id, also make the key expires within an hour or some soon future value (within tens of minutes or hours), send a link including the token to the user email (i.e. `example.com/login/token/{TOKEN}`)
3. User visits his inbox and press on that link
4. Server checks for {TOKEN} key, if it exists, authenticate the user and redirect to homepage, if not redirect to some error page.

Is this approach secure, is there something hidden I can't figure out yet?
Also Note that this method authenticate the user with only `GET` methods. 
I use Django/Python, so if there is some package doing that, what is it?
Also is it relevant and secure for new user registrations/password-change/other user checks? Is there impact in case of DDoS attacks like making my server spam random emails, consuming the server using having a big Redis memory consumption in short time?

For token generation, I will use some value generated by `random.SystemRandom().choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')`
long enough to be hard to guess ( 60-80 characters) and it is valid for a short time like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used it in production quite successfully at my company. However, the use case is a bit different, as we use it for inter-service authentication once user has logged in using the password.

Spamming of random email addresses using your service is quite a real possibility in this scheme and you would have to put in checks like Captcha etc. to ensure this does not happen.

For actual implementation refer to this link:
[Is there a way to configure Django Rest Framework to store token information in Redis rather than the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502422/is-there-a-way-to-configure-django-rest-framework-to-store-token-information-in)